# Cross reference is not properly anchored

Tags: cross-referencing

I've got a written code like this

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin={2cm,2.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={...},
    pdfauthor={...},
    pdfsubject={...},
    pdfkeywords={...},
}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{etoolbox,cancel,mathtools,physics}

\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
\counterwithin*{equation}{enumi}

\newif\ifinenumerate
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\inenumeratetrue}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theequation{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection.\else
  \ifnum\value{section}>0 \thesection.\fi\fi
  \ifinenumerate \theenumi\fi
  \arabic{equation}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test 1}
\subsection{Test 1.1}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item item a
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item a case 1         
        \begin{equation*}
        a = b
        \end{equation*}             
        \begin{itemize}
        \item item a case 1 subcase 1       
        \begin{equation}
        a = b \label{eq:Eq1.1.a.1}
        \end{equation}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{equation}
    a = b \label{eq:Eq1.1.a.2}
    \end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{Test 1.2}
\begin{equation} 
\underbrace{
            \cancel{\pdv{t}\delta n}
            }_{
               \mathclap{\substack{\text{stationary} \\ \text{case}}}
              } 
              + 
\underbrace{
            \cancel{\mu^*\va{E}\grad_{\va{r}}{\var n}}
            }_{
               \substack{\mu^* = 0 \\ \text{if} \\ n_0 = p_0 = n_i}
              } 
              - 
D^*\laplacian_{\va{r}}\delta n 
              - 
\underbrace{
            \frac{\delta n}{\tau^*}
            }_{
               \mathclap{\substack{\text{it vanishes for} \\ \text{lengths less than}\ L}}
              } 
              - 
g_L = 0 \label{eq:AmbipEq}
\end{equation}
\subsection{Test 1.3}
Cross reference to \eqref{eq:AmbipEq} which is not properly anchored 
\end{document}
```

And I would like to know why `eq:AmbipEq` is not properly anchored, maybe that's due `\mathclap` or `\substack` use? thank you so much!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not properly anchored".

Comment: When I do click in `\eqref` the document is not displaced to the right formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When testing your example, I got the line

```
\newlabel{eq:AmbipEq}{{1.2.1}{1}{Test 1.2}{equation.1.1}{}}
```

into the .aux-file.

This means that referencing the label `eq:AmbipEq` leads to "printing" the number `1.2.1` while linking to an anchor whose name is `equation.1.1` .

The .log-file contains some warnings. One of them is:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equation.1.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

This means that for some reason there were two attempts at placing an anchor whose name is `equation.1.1`.
Every hyperlink does link to that place in the output-file/.pdf-file which corrresponds to the place in the .TeX-input-file/source-file where the attempt of placing that anchor took place the first time.

What is the reason for this?:

The macro `\theequation` is used for specifying how to "print" the value of the equation counter.

When you use the hyperref-package, there is — besides printing the value — another issue:

When a new instance of a numbered "item of rubrification" is placed into the output-file (pdf-file), i.e., a numbered sectioning-heading, or the caption of a numbered picture, or the caption of a numbered table, or the number of a formula/an equation, both the value of the corresponding counter is printed and an anchor for hyperlinks is placed.
That anchor needs a name which is unique within the entire document.

The macro `\theHequation` is used for specifying the way in which anchor-names related to equation-numbers will be generated automatically when the hyperref-package is in use.

**The macro `\theHequation` must be specified in a way which ensures uniqueness of anchor-names.**

**When you redefine/change `\theequation`, you probably need to adjust/redefine `\theHequation` as well in order to ensure uniqueness of anchor-names.**

**Therefore I suggest parallel to placing**

```
\renewcommand\theequation{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection.\else
  \ifnum\value{section}>0 \thesection.\fi\fi
  \ifinenumerate \csname theenum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname\fi
  \arabic{equation}%
}
```

**placing something like**

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\theHequation{%
    \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \theHsubsection.\else
    \ifnum\value{section}>0 \theHsection.\fi\fi
    \ifinenumerate \csname theHenum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname.\fi
    \arabic{equation}%
  }%
}
```

**into the preamble of your document.**

(For both code snippets `@`being made a letter (→ `\makeatletter..\makeatother`) is assumed.)

When doing this, I get into the .aux-file an entry

```
\newlabel{eq:AmbipEq}{{1.2.1}{1}{Test 1.2}{equation.1.2.1}{}}
```

which means that referencing the label `eq:AmbipEq` leads to "printing" the number `1.2.1`  while linking to an anchor whose name is `equation.1.2.1` .

The corresponding pdfTeX-warning about destination with same identifier doesn't occur within the .log-file.

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin={2cm,2.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={...},
    pdfauthor={...},
    pdfsubject={...},
    pdfkeywords={...},
}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{etoolbox,cancel,mathtools,physics}

\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
\counterwithin*{equation}{enumi}

\newif\ifinenumerate
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\inenumeratetrue}

\newcommand{\prr}{\\[0.5cm]} %

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theequation{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection.\else
  \ifnum\value{section}>0 \thesection.\fi\fi
  \ifinenumerate \csname theenum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname\fi
  \arabic{equation}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\theHequation{%
    \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \theHsubsection.\else
    \ifnum\value{section}>0 \theHsection.\fi\fi
    \ifinenumerate \csname theHenum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname.\fi
    \arabic{equation}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test 1}
\subsection{Test 1.1}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item item a
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item a case 1
        \begin{equation*}
        a = b
        \end{equation*}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item item a case 1 subcase 1
        \begin{equation}
        a = b \label{eq:Eq1.1.a.1}
        \end{equation}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{equation}
    a = b \label{eq:Eq1.1.a.2}
    \end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{Test 1.2}
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{
            \cancel{\pdv{t}\delta n}
            }_{
               \mathclap{\substack{\text{stationary} \\ \text{case}}}
              }
              +
\underbrace{
            \cancel{\mu^*\va{E}\grad_{\va{r}}{\var n}}
            }_{
               \substack{\mu^* = 0 \\ \text{if} \\ n_0 = p_0 = n_i}
              }
              -
D^*\laplacian_{\va{r}}\delta n
              -
\underbrace{
            \frac{\delta n}{\tau^*}
            }_{
               \mathclap{\substack{\text{it vanishes for} \\ \text{lengths less than}\ L}}
              }
              -
g_L = 0 \label{eq:AmbipEq}
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
n &= N_C e^{\left(\frac{E_F-E_C}{K_B T}\right)} \nonumber
\prr
\frac{N_D^+}{N_D^0} &= \frac{1}{g_D}e^{\left(\frac{E_D-E_F}{K_BT}\right)} \label{eq:EqToLabeling}
\end{align}
\subsection{Test 1.3}
Cross reference to \eqref{eq:AmbipEq} which is hopefully properly anchored

Cross reference to \eqref{eq:EqToLabeling} which is hopefully properly anchored as well.
\end{document}
```

By the way:

I think it is important to learn about the reading-apparatus of (La)TeX and about the circumstances under which (La)TeX will produce space-tokens (yielding horizontal space in the output file) when encountering a space-character in the input file.
E.g., a space-character in the input-file after an opening-brace-character or after a closing-brace-character will yield a space-token leading to horizontal space in the output file (if that space-token is encountered when (La)TeX is not in one of its vertical modes).
E.g., a line break after an opening-brace-character or after a closing-brace-character will yield a space-token as well. That's because when reading input, (La)TeX inserts a space-character at the end of each line — this has to do with the integer-parameter `\endlinechar`.

Consider using the comment-char `%` after opening-brace-characters at line-endings and after closing-brace-characters at line-endings , i.e.,`{%` or  `}%`, in order to avoid unwanted horizontal space within the output-file/pdf-file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\TeXA{\TeX{
}\TeX}

\newcommand\TeXB{\TeX{}
\TeX}

\newcommand\TeXC{\TeX{%
}\TeX}

\newcommand\TeXD{\TeX{}%
\TeX}

\begin{document}

\noindent There are subtle differences in spacing:

\noindent \TeXA

\noindent \TeXB

\noindent \TeXC

\noindent \TeXD

\end{document}
```

Comment: But this not works properly when you use also `align` environment.

Comment: @jfernan Please provide an example which people can have compiled in order to see your way of using the align environment and to reproduce errors/erroneous results of the usage of the align environment.

Comment: I get the following log error when I use your solution http://pastebin.com/wJpYrKbi

Comment: You should be able to reproduce this isse with this code http://pastebin.com/B6mGLLs1

Comment: I think that your solution is not compatible with the fact of enumerate equations including the item `\ifinenumerate \theenumi\fi` (at least when the items are labeled by **italic** letters), so ... sorry, I will not considerate as a properly solution; however, I consider right point ensure uniqueness of anchor-names.

Comment: Well, right, that was the point exactly, after so many experiments to ensure uniqueness of anchor-names **is need that labels in `enumerate` environment won't be format text**. I rectify my position, I think it's better ensure uniqueness of anchors that typography in labels. Your solution is enough!

Comment: @jfernan I messed up in the first round: Due to the simple `\let`-assignment, things like `\thesection`, `\thesubsection` and `\theenumi` slipped into my redefinition of `\theHequation`.  This was a big big mistake of mine. Should be `\theHsection`, `\theHsubsection` and `\theHenumi`. Therefore a `\renewcommand`is needed. Stupid me!  Instead of `\theenumi`I resorted to the construct `\csname theenum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname` which - I hope - does take into account the possibility of nesting enumerate environments. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Perfect! Now I can keep `\textit{}` format to `enumerate` environment labels! Good job and thank you so much!